# ORTOOLS - CPSAT - Objective to minimize a value by intervals

Tags: or-tools, cp-sat

I my model in ORTools CPSAT, I am computing a variable called salary_var (among others). I need to minimize an objective. Let’s call it « taxes ».

to compute the taxes, the formula is not linear but organised this way:

if salary_var below 10084, taxes corresponds to 0%
between 10085 and 25710, taxes corresponds to 11%
between 25711 and 73516, taxes corresponds to 30%
and 41% for above

For example, if salary_var is 30000 then, taxes are:

(25710-10085) * 0.11 + (30000-25711) * 0.3 = 1718 + 1286 = 3005

My question: how can I efficiently code my « taxes » objective?

Thanks for your help
Seb

Answer (score 2):

This task looks rather strange, there is not much context and some parts of the task might touch some not-so-nice areas of finite-domain based solvers (large domains or scaling / divisions during solving).

Therefore: consider this as an idea / template!

### Code

```python
from ortools.sat.python import cp_model

# Data
INPUT = 30000
INPUT_UB = 1000000
TAX_A = 11
TAX_B = 30
TAX_C = 41

# Helpers

# new variable which is constrained to be equal to: given input-var MINUS constant
# can get negative / wrap-around
def aux_var_offset(model, var, offset):
    aux_var = model.NewIntVar(-INPUT_UB, INPUT_UB, "")
    model.Add(aux_var == var - offset)
    return aux_var

# new variable which is equal to the given input-var IFF >= 0; else 0
def aux_var_nonnegative(model, var):
    aux_var = model.NewIntVar(0, INPUT_UB, "")
    model.AddMaxEquality(aux_var, [var, model.NewConstant(0)])
    return aux_var


# Model
model = cp_model.CpModel()

# vars
salary_var = model.NewIntVar(0, INPUT_UB, "salary")
tax_component_a = model.NewIntVar(0, INPUT_UB, "tax_11")
tax_component_b = model.NewIntVar(0, INPUT_UB, "tax_30")
tax_component_c = model.NewIntVar(0, INPUT_UB, "tax_41")

# constraints
model.AddMinEquality(tax_component_a, [
    aux_var_nonnegative(model, aux_var_offset(model, salary_var, 10085)),
    model.NewConstant(25710 - 10085)])

model.AddMinEquality(tax_component_b, [
    aux_var_nonnegative(model, aux_var_offset(model, salary_var, 25711)),
    model.NewConstant(73516 - 25711)])

model.Add(tax_component_c == aux_var_nonnegative(model,
                                aux_var_offset(model, salary_var, 73516)))

tax_full_scaled = tax_component_a * TAX_A + tax_component_b * TAX_B + tax_component_c * TAX_C

# Demo
model.Add(salary_var == INPUT)

solver = cp_model.CpSolver()
status = solver.Solve(model)
print(list(map(lambda x: solver.Value(x), [tax_component_a, tax_component_b, tax_component_c, tax_full_scaled])))
```

### Output

```
[15625, 4289, 0, 300545]
```

### Remarks

As implemented:

- uses scaled solving
- produces scaled solution (300545)
- no fiddling with non-integral / ratio / rounding stuff BUT large domains

Alternative:

- Maybe something around `AddDivisionEquality`

### Edit in regards to Laurents comments

In some scenarios, solving the scaled problem but being able to reason about the *real* unscaled values easier might make sense.

If i interpret the comment correctly, the following would be a demo (which i was not aware of and it's cool!):

##### Updated Demo Code (partial)

```
# Demo -> Attempt of demonstrating the objective-scaling suggestion
model.Add(salary_var >= 30000)
model.Add(salary_var <= 40000)

model.Minimize(salary_var)

model.Proto().objective.scaling_factor = 0.001   # DEFINE INVERSE SCALING

solver = cp_model.CpSolver()
solver.parameters.log_search_progress = True     # SCALED BACK OBJECTIVE PROGRESS

status = solver.Solve(model)
print(list(map(lambda x: solver.Value(x), [tax_component_a, tax_component_b, tax_component_c, tax_full_scaled])))
print(solver.ObjectiveValue())                   # SCALED BACK OBJECTIVE
```

##### Output (excerpt)

```
...
...
#1       0.00s best:30    next:[30,29.999]  fixed_bools:0/1
#Done    0.00s  

CpSolverResponse summary:
status: OPTIMAL
objective: 30
best_bound: 30
booleans: 1
conflicts: 0
branches: 1
propagations: 0
integer_propagations: 2
restarts: 1
lp_iterations: 0
walltime: 0.0039022
usertime: 0.0039023
deterministic_time: 8e-08
primal_integral: 1.91832e-07

[15625, 4289, 0, 300545]
30.0
```

Comment: You can set the scaling of the objective to negate the scaling of the double when printing the search log (which you are not doing here).